# PowerShell - concatenate a calculated property with another selected field

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am simply trying to concatenate two columns from my result set. I want to concatenate the columns **SamAccountName** and **domain**

[image]
Here's the code:

```
$ad_list = Get-Content C:\AD\ad_groups.txt
$domain = "@domain.com"
ForEach ($ad_group in $ad_list) { 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ad_group -Server MyServer | 
        Select-Object Name,SamAccountName, @{Name='domain';Expression={$domain}} , @{Name='Ad_Group';Expression={$ad_group}} 
}
```

Comment: So, you want 3 columns (Name,SAMAccountName@Domain,AD_Group) instead of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expression would look like `{$_.SamAccountName + $domain}`, I've edited domain in the below example

```
$ad_list = Get-Content C:\AD\ad_groups.txt
$domain = "@domain.com"
ForEach ($ad_group in $ad_list) { 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ad_group -Server MyServer | 
        Select-Object Name,SamAccountName, @{Name='domain';Expression={$_.SamAccountName + $domain}} , @{Name='Ad_Group';Expression={$ad_group}} 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks! I got super close, just didn't have the "$_." in front of the SamAccountName field.

Comment: @mmassey10 Great, don't forget to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers